# Css :not style outside element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to change the font and bold the `<strong>` elements that are outside of `div.main2`, but leave elements inside `div.main2` unaffected.

I tried using  `:not(.main2)` and `strong *:not(.main2)` but the logic seemed wrong.

The idea is to get something like :

> **TITULO TITULO**
>
> TITULO TITULO

You can check the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/_PSYCKIC_/57PGJ/) in order to work it out.

---

#### UPDATE:

For example in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_PSYCKIC_/wcFyQ/)

> **Titulo Titulo**
>
> Titulo Titulo
>
> Titulo Titulo

Should be like :

> **Titulo Titulo**
>
> **Titulo Titulo**
>
> Titulo Titulo

in the future can had tables , other divs wit other things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is use two rules instead:

```
.main strong {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.main2 strong {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yb6RU/)

---

<strike>If you're really looking for a CSS3 solution, you can use this:</strike>

```
.main :not(.main2) strong, .main > strong {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/_PSYCKIC_/bX3T8/1/ the problem is this one the last TITULO shouldn't be like this

Comment: Seems is nice for the first approach with the second CSS3 seems not :( Thanks for the help

Comment: @Ricardo: Oh, good point. Yep, the CSS3 approach won't work. But really, there's no reason to use it.